# SQL JOIN proving impossible to sort out? Split it

Tags: php, mysql, class, methods, pdo

EDIT: I was new to SQL and got lost in `JOIN`s when I wrote this. Took me ages to realize that you can just do the `SELECTS` separately. OK it is processed a fraction slower than a `JOIN` but for learners and/or small databases it is virtually the same and makes code **much** more readable. I still do most `JOIN` type operations as sequential operations.

Yeah I know all you SQL Superstars -  I better go the the naughty step.

===========================================

ORIGINAL POST WHICH WAS CURED WITH A TYPO CORRECTION

I am still struggling with classes but getting there slowly.

My next job was to get all sorts of MySQL loops tucked nicely inside classes.

I THINK I have solved the problem of getting my standardised PDO call into the method by passing it as an attribute (I cold not use the normal `include` in the class for some reason).

So my call to instantiate the class was:

```
$getval= new Transmission;
$resx= $getval->retrieveTransmission($person,$pdo);
debug($resx);
```

So I hope I am passing an instance of my default PDO set up by an include on the page which is:

```
try
{
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hjoyjoy;dbname=$dhaphap", $usadsad, $pborbor);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{ blah blah    };
```

I instantiated a new Transmission object and called it:

```
    $getval= new Transmission;
    $resx= $getvalretrieve->Transmission($person,$pdo);
    debug($resx);
```

In the Transmission class (code currently on the page working fine) I tried:

```
public function retrieveTransmission($id,$pdo){  
    try
{   $sql = 
    "SELECT id FROM transmission 
    WHERE person_id = :person;";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':person',$person, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    $result=$statement ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    return($result);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'Error getting messages ready to display #6734: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/vvvxxx/includes/output.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

This is then supposed to go into a

```
foreach ($resx as $row)
```

which does another `SELECT` loop.

So is there a fairly straightforward way of taking about 10 of these `SELECT/UPDATE/STORE/DELETE` loops and safely tucking them inside classes as I build this thing out?

Comment: if you're using the results of one query to run other queries, you should be writing a single JOINed query instead.

Comment: First, you pass in `$id` yet use `$person`. Is this a typo? Second, I imagine you'd want `$statement->fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()`. At least, that's what I gathered from your `foreach($resx as $row)`

Comment: @Phil thank you thank you x 1 million. All working as I hoped. (Not as I expected but as I hoped.) I haven't programmed for around 40 YEARS so I am a little rusty! Once again thanks. Tomorrow I can dump all those loops into classes and everything will be a thousand times cleaner.

Comment: @Marc B. I used to use JOINed queries (and I expect I will later on) but building a tiny first version I can see no real disadvantage to not using JOIN. I can maybe see problems for UPDATE or STORE later on but even there with judicious error checking I think nested simple queries will work in nearly everything I have planned for now... and they are  hell of a lot easier to debug for a newb. But thanks for the valid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a typo.

I also realize that not using JOINed queries is "bad form" but when you are starting out doing several *simple* queries make things easier to understand.